# My search bar isn't working and I cant figure out why. VB.net/Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        '  Dim i As Integer
        Dim sql As String
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        conn.Open()
        sql = “Select * from tblBooks where AUTHOR like '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = sql

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

my search button is currently looking like this. Id appreciate any help

Comment: What is ex.message content?

Answer (score 2):

Do not declare connections outside of the method where they are used. Connections, commands and DataReaders have a `Dispose` method which must be called to release unmanaged resources. The language provides `Using` blocks to close and dispose these objects.

**Never** concatenate strings to build sql strings. **Always** use parameters to avoid sql injection.

You set up a command but you never executed it and even if you did execute it you haven't provided any way to display the return.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql = "Select * from tblBooks where AUTHOR like @Author;"
    Try
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Author", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = $"*{TextBox1.Text}*"
            conn.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dt.Load(reader)
            End Using 'Closes and disposes reader
        End Using 'Closes and disposes connection and disposes command
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: @djv Thank you for correcting that. My 74 year old eyes didn't catch it. Interesting enough, it appears the compiler interprets fancy quotes as regular double quotes. `MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt32("““"c).ToString) 'displays 34'

Comment: Oh my Mary you have just about lapped me in years. This explains why you have so much time on your hands :)

Comment: Still working, in manufacturing, part of continuous improvement is the mantra "see it, own it", and combined with my attention to detail... well let's just say I edit a lot!

Answer (score -1):

As is, it will only return an exact match. Try adding wildcards:

```
sql = "Select * from tblBooks where AUTHOR like '*" & TextBox1.Text & "*'"
```

Comment: Please don't encourage concatenation of strings to build sql commands. The problem of sql injection is introduced with user input in a text box.

Comment: @Mary: A direct question deserves a direct answer.